# mount root FS read only with docker-compose

Tags: security, docker, docker-compose

I try to apply the docker CIS (https://github.com/docker/docker-bench-security)

The test 5.13 is: `Mount container's root filesystem as read only`
There is an option for docker run to mount the root FS read only: `--read-only=true`
But I can't find the possibility to achieve the same with docker-compose.

Is there a possibility to mount the root FS read only with docker-compose?

Comment: Actually, that was wrong, it is available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `read_only:` in the compose file https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#read_only

Comment: The you provided does not reference `read_only`.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#read_only